# Java Web Application Project development for two clients

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, maven-2

I'm developing a web-project based on Spring (MVC), Hibernate, PostgreSQL (using Maven). Now I'm trying to get a new customer who requires some differences in several parts of the application. I've read the Maven Definitive Guide from Sonatype to get a feeling about Multi-modules Maven Projects but one of my most important questions has not been answered there: How can I share common view-components over several modules/projects and integrate them depending on the customer I want to build for? The Service-Layer is pretty clear but I can't figure out how to share jsp/jspf files and merge them with the custom files when building the specific customer-module (which then depends on the common-module).

How would you try to avoid just simply cloning the commonly used code?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Especially the Maven Dependency Plugin seems to be useful. I have come over another solution using the Maven WAR Plugin and the overlays of it. You can then add a dependency on another war and reuse parts of that (common war e.g.). The Remote Resource Plugin seems to be made mainly for license distribution, but might also do the job.

Comment: you should add such comments either to the answers you are referring to or edit your original question. Also: the StackOverflow version of saying "Thanks for your answers" is clicking the up arrows on them, althogh verbal thanks are also appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

> I can't figure out how to share jsp/jspf files and merge them with the custom files when building the specific customer-module (which then depends on the common-module).

This looks like a good use case for [Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can put common components in a library project and unpack them as needed using [dependency:unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) or [dependency:unpack-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html)

E.g. you project layout would be like that:

```
root
 |____ common-lib (jar, contains common java code)
 |____ common-gui (jar, contains only non-java stuff like js, jsp, css etc) 
 |____ client1    (war)
 |____ client2    (war)
```

client1 and client2 would each have a regular `compile` dependency to common-lib, but only a `provided` dependency to common-gui (if you use `dependency:unpack` it doesn't have to be a project dependency at all)

Now you'd add code like this to your client projects:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-common-gui-elements</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
                        <artifactId>common-gui</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <!--  war assembly directory -->
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*.jsp,**/*.css,**/*.js</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That way you can re-use your components but you can always choose yourself which components you distribute to which client.

Comment: This is another way and can be useful too so +1. It reminds me of [How to share resources across projects in Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/).